# Add Standalone ASP.Net Application Into Existing ASP.Net Website

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, ssl-certificate

I have a weird question for everyone. I am currently working on a project for a company that has an existing ASP.Net website that they have lost all source code for. I need to add some functionality to the site but they are not willing to pay for a site redesign right now.

Can I deploy my web application to a subdirectory of their website and have it function properly? I have to do this because I need to take advantage of the SSL certificate they have attached to the existing website (unfortunately it is not a wildcard cert).

They are running Windows Server 2008 SR2 with IIS 7.5. The current ASP.Net website uses forms authentication. My web app also uses forms authentication.

Is this doable? I have never ran into it and don't know the answer. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a sub-folder under the root of the website, then go into IIS Manager, select that folder, right click on it and then click `Convert to application`. This will allow you to create a separate application for that folder so that it will be treated separately by IIS. You can create a new application alias in the same application pool as the root website but you can also run it in a totally different / new application pool in case you want it to run under a different .NET version.

Answer (score 0):

whilst you could deploy your new website it almost certainly will not work as it will most likely use a different version of the framework that the old one.

you could create a new site in iis and deploy your site there and configure iis to use the newer framework version, however you still have two issues:
1. the ssl cert, depending on the cert and your iis config it may not work
2. how do people navigate from the old site to the new one?  if you cannot modify the source how will you add links?

Comment: Wouldn't it work to create the new site as an IIS application under the original? Wouldn't that use a separate AppDomain?

Comment: I can modify the aspx pages and figured I could add a hard link into the existing site. I just don't have any of the code behind C# code because the only instance of the application is compiled.

Also would the Virtual Directory setup work or would that actually redirect them to someotherdomain/myapp?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure.  yo'd have to try it I imagine, it's not something I've actually come accross before.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Reflector from RedGate to decompile it.  That would give you all of the source-code back.  It would be much safer.