# Adding a Standalone Application Into Existing ASP.Net Website

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have the exact same problem that is described in this question:

[Add Standalone ASP.Net Application Into Existing ASP.Net Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15689412/add-standalone-asp-net-application-into-existing-asp-net-website)

However the solution that is marked as correct isn't working for me. Here's my scenario:

I'm writing an Asp.net web application for a company that needs it to run under a site which runs a 3rd party application for which I don't have the source code (it needs to run here so that it can share the same authentication if possible). I have created a sub-directory in the root of the site and converted it into an application. I even gave it a separate app pool.

However, when I try to browse to this new app, it started throwing various config errors. It's apparently reading from the parent site's web.config file. It is trying to load various handlers and a role manager. So, I added those same sections to my config but added a clear /> element. Problem solved.

However, now it's giving me compiler errors:

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'NamespaceX' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
public virtual NamespaceX.NamespaceY.Framework.Bus.PortalPageCollection PortalPageCollection2 {
get {
return ((NamespaceX.NamespaceY.Framework.Bus.PortalPageCollection)        (this.GetPropertyValue("PortalPageCollection2")));
}
```

"NamespaceX.NamespaceY.Framework.Bus.PortalPageCollection" is the name of one of their Dll's.

Why would this be happening in a separate app even after I've given it a separate application pool?

Thanks!

Comment: Why didn't the solution work for you? You will have to convert it to its own application for it to run separate of the parent application. A separate appPool will not achieve this.

Comment: I was under the impression that I had done that. From IIS, in the root of the already existing site, I right clicked my subdirectory and chose "Add Application." This I did right after I made that a virtual directory.